# how to use mysqlconnection throughout the application

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to have a MySQL connection open in the main form. However, O am having trouble trying use the connection in other forms.

How should I set it up so that I only need to open the connection once in the whole program, and use the same connection to get data from database.

Or should I have a new connection open in each form?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to just leave a connection open the whole time the app is running.  It's better to create a single function that you can call repeatedly if your goal is to simplify code readability.  The below example is as basic as it gets, but you'll need to do a bit more for stored procedures and Parameter objects not in a query string.  All this will do is fill a datatable.

```
public DataTable RunQuery(string query)
{
//connectionString should come from your configuration or a constant that is a part of this class
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                 sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
   return dt;    
}
```

Calling it is easy.

```
RunQuery("Select * from myData");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use using statement with SQL connection as follow:

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            //Your code goes here
        }
```

and make the connection string in App.config file.

Comment: how about myConnection(); ? where should i put it?

Comment: every time open the connection when needed using the statement to make sure the connection is disposed.

Comment: from what you suggest, i will need to open and close the connection each time when i need to use it, is it correct? Is it better to do it this way, or have the connection open only ONCE until the program is closed?

Comment: Yes, create a manager class for operations needed in db and make it accessible by all forms, and inside this class for each db operation a new connection will be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to open your MySqlConnection once, and then reuse your connection with using, or by checking it´s state. It is the same as every ADO.NET library. Using the `using`statement you have guarantee that the object will be disposed and all resources released.

This link has everithing you need about working with MySql: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL